# URL parameters aren't passing between pages on my WordPress Website

Tags: php, wordpress, url, google-analytics, url-parameters

Here is a short example of URL parameters that we would use:

example.com/article-1/?utm_campaign=marge&utm_source=google

The strategy of this website, being that we encourage seekers to explore other articles, we need to track as much as possible from our ads. We would want to know if a seeker converted on another article different than the first.

Currently if a user landed here:

example.com/article-1/?utm_campaign=marge&utm_source=google

Then clicked to another article here:

example.com/article-2/ , We lose the parameters and Google Analytics could only show us that our seeker stayed on one page. What can be done so that we could pass that information in the URL along with any page?

Answer (score 0):

`utm_medium` in mandatory, anyway you should not use UTMs for internal links because they generate anomalies in report, rather use different parameters, e.g., `?from=article`